elastic 8 search aggs filter on (source.geo.country_iso_code)
Im porting a query from ELK 6 to ELK 8. The field names have changed significantly between these versions.
In ELK 6, the field was geoip.country_code2. In ELK8 its changed to source.geo.country_iso_code.
But when I try to filter on that field, its not picking anything up.
I can dump out the hits, and see the field with values. But my filter doesnt collect them.
I can see hits containing fields like
"source":{"geo":{"country_iso_code":"AU"},"address":"123.208.218.163"}
Basically the same filter works in ELK6. So it must be something to do with differences between ELK6 and ELK8
My query is as follows
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
     "filter":[
       {"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":"<lower>","lt":"<upper>"}}}
      ],
      "must": [
        {"match": {"http.response.status_code":"200"}},
        {"match": {"vhost":"<vhost>"}}
      ]
   }
  },
  "_source" ["url.original","vhost","@timestamp","http.response.body.bytes","source.address","source.geo.country_iso_code"],
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "AU": {
      "filter": {
        "term": { "source.geo.country_iso_code": "AU"}
      },
      "aggs": { 
        "sum_bytes": { "sum": {"field": "http.response.body.bytes"}},
        "ip_count": { "cardinality": { "field": "source.address" }}
      }
    },
    "int": {
      "filter": { 
        "bool": { "must_not": { "term": { "source.geo.country_iso_code": "AU" }}}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_bytes": { "sum": {"field": "http.response.body.bytes"}},
        "ip_count": { "cardinality": { "field": "source.address" }}
      }
    }
  }
}

But everything ends up in the int bucket. With nothing in the AU bucket.

Can you please provide sample data? Also, Please post output of index mapping.

OK, someones pointed me to the solution.
Apparently I cant filter on text fields directly. I have to use the keyword subfield. So source.geo.country_iso_code.keyword.
This is mentioned in the documentation on terms aggregations. Whereas this is a filter aggregation. But apparently the same thing applies.
